# Dividend Yield Goyal and Welch (2008)

Tags: equities, data, finance, dividends

Following the Goyal and Welch (2008) stock return predictability data, does anyone know how they calculate the dividend yield from the dataset that they provide on Amit Goyals website http://www.hec.unil.ch/agoyal/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They define the dividend yield calculation in the beginning of the paper:

Dividend ratios are the total dividends paid by all stocks (D(t)), divided
by the total stock market capitalization, either at the beginning of the year (the dividend yield, P(t − 1) or at the end of the year (the dividend-price ratio,
P(t)).